# Aggregation on 2 columns while keeping two unique R

Tags: r, aggregate, aggregate-functions

So I have this:

```
Staff   Result  Date  Days
1       50      2007  4
1       75      2006  5
1       60      2007  3
2       20      2009  3
2       11      2009  2
```

And I want to get to this:

```
Staff   Result  Date  Days
1       55      2007  7
1       75      2006  5
2       15      2009  5
```

I want to have the Staff ID and Date be unique in each row, but I want to sum 'Days' and mean 'Result'

I can't work out how to do this in R, I'm sure I need to do lots of aggregations but I keep getting different results to what I am aiming for.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the simplest way to do this is to `group_by` Staff and Date and summarise the results with `dplyr` package:

```
require(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(Staff = c(1,1,1,2,2),
             Result = c(50, 75, 60, 20, 11),
             Date = c(2007, 2006, 2007, 2009, 2009),
             Days = c(4, 5, 3, 3, 2)) 

df %>% 
   group_by(Staff, Date) %>% 
   summarise(Result = floor(mean(Result)),
             Days = sum(Days)) %>% 
   data.frame

   Staff Date Result Days
1      1 2006     75    5
2      1 2007     55    7
3      2 2009     15    5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `aggregate` on two variables by using a formula and then `merge` the two aggregates

```
merge(aggregate(Result ~ Staff + Date, data=df, mean),
    aggregate(Days ~ Staff + Date, data=df, sum))
  Staff Date Result Days
1     1 2006   75.0    5
2     1 2007   55.0    7
3     2 2009   15.5    5
```

Comment: This also works thank you! Codutie answered first so I clicked his as correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(Result = floor(mean(Result)), Days = sum(Days)), .(Staff, Date)]
#   Staff Date Result Days
#1:     1 2007     55    7
#2:     1 2006     75    5
#3:     2 2009     15    5
```